# Spanish keyboard set ! to ¡

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I'm using emacs 26.0.50.1 in my spanish laptop and keyboard. Emacs has binding to the ! key for examle

M-! => M-x shell-command

In a Spanish keyboard this is impossible (at least for me) to amke with one hand

So I write this to the init.el

(global-set-key (kbd "M-¡") 'shell-command)

now i use two hands also but it is better than M-shift-1.

In magit there are key binding to !-p, so how can I change ! (shift-1) to ¡, for my emacs globally but still can write !